# derby identity column not goes in sequense

Tags: java, sql, derby

I created a table , embedded Derby:

```
create table  someTable(id integer  generated always as identity(start with 1,increment by 1),editor varchar(10))
```

Problem is I get such table :

```
ID,EDITOR

1,counter

2,counter

3,counter

4,counter

5,counter

6,counter

7,counter

8,counter

9,counter

10,counter

11,counter

12,counter

13,counter

14,counter

15,counter

115,counter

215,counter
```

sometimes when id is 10 then jumps to 116 ...I want id goes from 1 to 30 .
why such behavior happens ? and is there a way to fix ?
Knowing that the preallocater is set ( 1 to 30 as a counter) & the database shuts down normally ...in Derby manuals states that :If the database is shut down in an orderly fashion, Derby will not leak unused preallocated values

didn't see in question a case like this, for that I hope to get some help.

Comment: Why does it matter as long as you are getting unique values in it? ID doesn't need to be gapless

Comment: @GurwinderSingh ..made a counter when id hits 30 , trial period expires ...but with this jumping its hard to control

Comment: @GurwinderSingh.. after all Trial Users won't be happy after all if instead of 30 trial they get 5 or 6  times !!!

Comment: *"made a counter when id hits 30"* - That's not really what id columns should be used for, just count the number of rows if that's an issue